# Store Date Picker Jquery files in My server instead on getting from internet

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a local intranet site that will run in my company LAN. I want my users to pick dates from a datepicker. I want to keep the jquery files to be stored in my local server instead of the internet. Is there a way to do this? I have tried many online tutorials and no success. Can anyone show me how to store my datepicker jquery files locally on my local server?

Comment: Could you show the code that you currently use?

Comment: Is the question about storing files on your company server or adapting HTML to reference JavaScript files stored on your company's server?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code of jquery datepicker using. 
**JQuery include and Javascript is:**

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
         $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', firstDay: 1,minDate:1 });
</script>
```

**Input Tag:**

```
<input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker"/>
```

**In PHP Code:**

```
$date=$_POST['datepicker'];
```

This is a sample code of datepicker. In the above there are three external files are included. I  have included the files in cdn link. If you want to do it locally then download those  file and link locally. It will work same.

I am give you one more solution. If you only want the date then you need not use the datepicker. User HTML tag you can do that. Like,

```html
<input type="date" id"show_date">
```

In the PHP end you have the value in normal POST or GET array.

**Note:**
By default I set the date format in dd-mm-yyyy. You can change the format as you want. You can change it in JQuery or in PHP. Both gives you same result.

Comment: I suppose this is not the answer OP is looking for, afaik he would like to know how to server js files locally not from CDN

Comment: change the path according to you js file. Like  <script src="app/js/jquery.js"></script>. <br> This the example of call the file locally. In the example the 'jquery.js' is store with in the application folder app->js. So, it is same as any other js file.

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 The above jquery "jquery.min.js" is stored in the internet in this case. In my case, i want to store it in my server files instead of the internet. how can i do this. How can i download jquery.min.js and store it in my server and call it in my codes.

Comment: Jerzyk is right. That's exactly what i want. I want to know how to download the datepicker jquery file and store it in my local server and then call it in my javascript codes. Please tell where i can download the datepicker js file and store it locally on my local server.

Comment: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js. Open this link. Press Ctrl+S to save the file. Give any name and save the file into your system. Then copy the file into your local server. Link with that jquery file like '<script src="app/js/jquery.js"></script>'. That's it. Now for jquery you not need internet. It will work with out internet.

Comment: Thanks Avishake:
I did as you mentioned  as follows but still no luck. Refer my script below. I placed the jquery file in my server home folder.

<head>
 <script src="jqueryDatePicker/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script>

    $(function() {

     $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();

    });

   </script>
</head>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help. I solved this issue. I opened all the .js files from the INTERNET and saved them on my local server as advised by  Avishake and called them in my code and its all good now.